# Unable to load: custom OracleValidConnectionChecker

Tags: jboss, wildfly, datasource, wildfly-21

```
<validation>
    <valid-connection-checker class-name="com.rolfeandnolan.merlin.fmextensions.FMOracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
    <exception-sorter class-name="com.rolfeandnolan.merlin.fmextensions.FMOracleExceptionSorter"/>
</validation>
```

FMOracleValidConnectionChecker is custom OracleValidationConnectionChecker. It's working fine in wildfly 10 but giving below stacktrace in wildfly 20

```
java:/com/rolfeandnolan/merlin/datasources/NonTransactional: java.lang.Exception: Unable to load: com.rolfeandnolan.merlin.fmextensions.FMOracleValidConnectionChecker
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.loadPlugin(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:1215)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.isValidConnection(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:1292)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.getInvalidConnections(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:379)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:632)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:604)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:597)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1.obtainConnection(SessionFactoryImpl.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements(IdTableHelper.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.prepare(AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1250)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:658)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:212)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
```

---

```
Wildfly version 20
ojdbc version 8.0
```

Does anybody know how can I fix this problem?

Project structure -
Application.ear>-lib>-utility.jar
-META-INF
-*EJB.jar
-*.war

Comment: Where does your class live ? It should be part of the driver module I guess

Comment: class is in a utility jar which is under the lib folder in the root directory of .ear file.

Comment: I think it should be in the driver module

Comment: @ehsavoie can you tell me exactly where to put this utility jar? Thanks

Comment: @ehsavoie and there are other common classes(In utility jar) as well which are needed by EJB jars

Answer (score 0):

I think that the required classes should be in the "org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" module: so you need to add your jar there and add it to the module.xml